# wildcard htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, wildcard

i have installed wildcard on my server , and it's working fine

i used this htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.org$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^\.]+)\.domain\.org$ [NC]
```

when i open ( ddddddddddd.mydomain.com ) ,, i find my ( public_html files )

and That's exactly what i want

but here is small problem

i want know the requested subdomain by php

Example :

dadadadadad.mydomain.com

How i can know the 'dadadadadad' ?

BY PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PHP you can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`. It should return `dadadadadad.mydomain.com`. If you want only the subdomain part, here is the code:

```
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$host = explode(".",$host);

$subdomain = $host[0];

//var_dump($subdomain);
```

Comment: i tried that yeasterday and it's did't work !

it's working fine now !

thank you develroot very much